# How to get dependencies which are not on github through Carthage?

Tags: ios, carthage

I am trying to use only carthage for dependency manager. But what happens if the project is not available on github? What is work through for that?

Thanks

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39074536/4250188

Answer (score 2):

Using an example on Bitbucket you can do the following:

1. Setup SSH keys for the acct
2. use the direct ssh sync

   ```
   git "git@bitbucket.org:{acct}/{repo}.git"
   ```

In general that line can be used for any repo.

```
git "http://git.mypersonalserver.net/mySource/myrepo.git"
```

Comment: Just to be more precise: for any GIT repo.