# Carthage and GoogleMap

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods, carthage

Is it possible to install GoogleMap SDK via Carthage?

I only saw the tutorial for Cocoapods only.

Or I only can install manually if I am using Carthage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Carthage docs](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Artifacts.md#cartfile):

> The only supported origins right now are GitHub repositories (both GitHub.com and GitHub Enterprise)

Carthage actually builds binary framework from the sources it checkouts from the specified repository. Developer needs to link this built binary frameworks to the project afterwards.

Google already provides you with the binary version of GoogleMaps framework instead of sharing sources. Therefore all you have to do is just download this binary from [official website](https://developers.google.com/maps/) and link it to your project without using Carthage. So you can say that Google has already done Carthage work for you so you don't have to use Carthage to build GoogleMap framework. And I believe you even couldn't if you want to because GoogleMaps source code is not open.

Hope my answer will be helpful for you.

Comment: Carthage is dependency manager, so packaging and building is not the only reason to use it. It will help developer to keep all dependencies up to date if they add the support. I think google already started the task tho.
[link] (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827791)

Answer (score 5):

Carthage supports linking directly to binary assets. 
If you go to the "Manual Integration" section in the documentation page, you'll notice the download link looks something like this:

```
https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/d308af63f78a5a1a/GoogleMaps-3.1.0.tar.gz
```

So all you have to do is create a local JSON file called something like `GoogleMaps.json`, and put the following in it:

```
{
  "3.1.0" : "https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/d308af63f78a5a1a/GoogleMaps-3.1.0.tar.gz"
}
```

Then, in your `Cartfile`, add:

`binary "GoogleMaps.json" ~> 3.1.0`

Voila!

Comment: unfortunately I've faced an issue, `Unrecognized archive format` is the error I've received after using GoogleMaps.json in Cartfile, because of `tar.gz` fie type

Comment: looks like version 3.2 and 3.3 have some issue with the compression of the file

Answer (score 1):

Was just about to find out how to improve upon Shai's answer. You can simply add

`binary "https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-ios-utils/GoogleMapsSDK-iOS.json" ~> 3.8.0`

into your Cartfile

Answer (score 0):

I used Leone Parise github repo for google maps 2.7 https://github.com/leoneparise/GoogleMaps-Carthage

He has Google Places and Google Place Picker too, but not up to date. If you want to use those, I've them uploaded to 2.7 version here:
https://github.com/danitinez/GooglePlaces-Carthage
and here
https://github.com/danitinez/GooglePlacePicker-Carthage

Cheers!